# Selenium java find multiple Displayed elements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium with Java from the Mavenproject.

My code is working, I'm just wondering if it can be improved.
In the code below you can see I'm looking for a few elements and if they are displayed or not.

The issue is that I'm looking for tons of elements +- 50. 
So I have about 50 of these lines. I'm struggling to find a more efficient way. Isn't a easier way of writing this down in 1 line searching for multiple elements and checking if all are displayed?

Like Find.... A,B,C,D,...,Y,Z .isDisplayed?

```
    boolean function_detail_breadcrumb_1_displayed = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-core2='403']")).isDisplayed();
    boolean function_detail_breadcrumb_2_displayed = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-core2='405']")).isDisplayed();
    boolean function_detail_breadcrumb_3_displayed = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-core2='407']")).isDisplayed();
    boolean function_detail_breadcrumb_4_displayed = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-core2='410']")).isDisplayed();
    boolean function_detail_breadcrumb_5_displayed = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-core2='413']")).isDisplayed();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to check certain breadcrumbs:

```
String[] breadCrumbs = new String[]{"403", "405", "407", "410", "413"};
for (String breadCrumb : breadCrumbs) {
    String selector = String.format("[data-core2='%s']", breadCrumb);
    boolean breadCrumbDisplayed = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(selector)).isDisplayed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note: I am assuming, you are checking whether all elements are displayed or not.**

First, You find elements of the kinds:

```
List<WebElement> breadCrumbList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("Your selector"));
```

Then iterate through your breadcrumbs and check:

```
        List<WebElement> breadCrumbList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("Your selector"));
        boolean isAllDisplayed = true;
        for(WebElement breadCrumb : breadCrumbList){
            if(breadCrumb.isDisplayed() == false){
                isAllDisplayed = false;
                break;
            }
        }
```